# how to compare File/Stream Equality in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, equality, rxdart

How can I check Files/Stream equality in dart?

Like this:

```
File file1;
File file2;
file1.equals(file2) // false Or true
```

Or in Streams Like this:

```
Stream<Int8List> stream1;
Stream<Int8List> stream2;

stream1.equals(Stream2) // false Or true
```

And also in unit testing?

Comment: For unit tests, see: https://pub.dev/packages/test#stream-matchers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sequenceEqual](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/sequenceEqual.html) from `rxdart` package:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

Rx.sequenceEqual(
  stream1,
  stream2,
  const ListEquality<Int>().equals
).listen(print);
```